# wget file timestamp in local timezone

Tags: timezone, timestamp, wget

We use wget to download data files from different vendors across US. Eg, our server is in EST timezone, vendeor1's timezone is CST, and vendor2's timezone is PST.

The default behavior of wget is that the file's lastmodified timestamp will still be in the original timezone from the source. How do we get lastmodified timestamp in local server (EST) timezone?

Here is one example, file1 is downloaded from a vendor2's server located in California (PST/PDT). It does not make sense the lastmodified time is even before create time. The actual lastmodified time is Thu Sep 29 22:57:00 **PDT** 2016, which is Fri Sep 29 1:57:00 EDT 2016.

The reason we see the "wrong" lastmodified time is because of wget keep the time in the source's timezone. If we use wget to download data from server's other than EST, PST, and order files based on lastmodified we receive, then it will not be correct. Is there an easy way to use the destination servers' timezone when using wget? (At least all files' lastmodified timestamp will be in the same tiemzone, or unixtime since epoch)

```
file1 = '..../yyyymmdd.zip'
>>> os.path.getmtime(file1)
1475204220.0

>>> os.path.getctime(file1)
1475253907.1713214

$ date -d @1475204220
Thu Sep 29 22:57:00 EDT 2016

$ date -d @1475253907.1713214
Fri Sep 30 12:45:07 EDT 2016
```

Shouldnot the lastmodified be saved as timezone-less unix-style timestamp associates with the file? If it is timezone-less, then it does not matter where the server locates, or where the file transfer to or from (as the create timestamp of the file.) Then why does wget modify it?

Comment: What about setting the timezone of your server to GMT?  Using **wget -d** shows the HTTP headers have a **GMT** timezone.

Comment: I prefer leave the timezone to the correct setting. Tweaking the timezone will have unexpected consequences on other applications running on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bash script uses **wget** to get the file, writes it out with the same name, then adjusts the timestamp by using the **Last-Modified** or **Date** headers which are requested with **curl**.

```
#!/bin/bash

get_file() {
        echo 'Getting the file';
        `wget -q "$1" -O "$2"`;
        return $?
}

adjust_timestamp(){
        echo 'Adjusting the timestamp';
        FILEDATE=`curl -sI "$1" | grep Last-Modified`;
        if [ -z "$FILEDATE" ];
        then
                FILEDATE=`curl -sI "$1" | grep Date`;
        fi;
        FILEDATE=`echo "$FILEDATE" | sed "s/^[^:]\+: //"`;
        NEWDATE=`date --date="$FILEDATE"`;
        echo "File date from source server: $FILEDATE";
        ls -l $2;
        echo "Date adjusted for timezone: $NEWDATE";
        touch $2 -d "$NEWDATE";
        ls -l $2;
}

HOST='http://www.example.com';
FILE='robots.txt';
URL="$HOST/$FILE"

if get_file "$URL" "$FILE";
then
        adjust_timestamp "$URL" "$FILE";
fi;
```

**Sample output**

> Getting the file
>
> Adjusting the timestamp
>
> File date from source server: Thu, 27 Dec 2007 02:47:13 GMT
>
> -rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 481 Dec 26  2007 robots.txt
>
> Date adjusted for timezone: Wed Dec 26 21:47:13 EST 2007
>
> -rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 481 Dec 26  2007 robots.txt

This is making two (or three) requests.  You may want to enhance the script to only make one request.